# How to get client_id & client_secret in Kounta To use Basic Access Authorization?

Tags: php, rest, api, curl, oauth

I want to use Kounta API for my application but I am unable to find `client_id` and the client secret in Kounta account. Without it's not possible to get authorize client from API. Anyone experts in Kounta here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic auth will get you access to just one company in Kounta, so if you're just building a one off integration that's fine. If not then best to use oauth 2.

Documentation for their API can be found here: https://kounta.com/documentation

To get basic auth for a customer's company you need to:

1. Ensure the customer has at least one of their Sites on the Extend billing plan.
2. Notify developers@kounta.com and they can enable API access for one or more users.
3. Once activated, log in, go to add-ons (if in a multi-site company choose the site on the extend plan), tap create new add-on. This has all the basic auth credentials for that company.

For more info contact developers@kounta.com

Comment: Thanks @josh-harrison & jodm.